# How get objects from through model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have such models:

```
class PortfolioAlbum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField() 
    photo = models.ManyToManyField(PortfolioAlbum, through='AlbumPhotos')


class AlbumPhotos(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(PortfolioAlbum)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio)
    title = models.CharField()
    photo = ThumbnailerImageField()
```

How i can get my AlbumPhotos (field - 'photo') within context of my 'Portfolio' page?

i tryed so last time:

```
<ul>
{% for albumphotos in portfolios %}
<li><img src="{{ albumphotos.photo.image150x150.url }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

.. and some examples too, but it was wrong.

Comment: Is `portfolios` a list of `Portfolio` objects? If so, then the HTML part doesn't make to much sense..

Answer (score 0):

`Photo` should be a fully fledged model on it's own, and have a foreign key or m2m relation with `Album`.

Anyways, to get through model's records you do the following:

```
portfolio = Portfolio.objects.get(…)
photos = portfolio.photo.through.filter(portfolio=portfolio)
```

This is really weird relation…

Instead you should be able to write:

```
portfolio = Portfolio.objects.get(…)
for album in portfolio:
    for photo in album:
        print photo
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Use:

```
protifolio.albumphoto_set.all()
```

to get all AlbumPhoto attached to a protfolio instance. When using many-to-one relation Django will automatically setup a reverse relation via **foo_set**.

Quite late but I post it anyway, for the *records*.